# Cannot delete the the many Zone.Identifier files testdisk left behind

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, testdisk, ntfs-3g

After successfully recovering many files from a Windows drive with a broken partition table with testdisk, I have noticed that for many filetypes, so-called Zone.Identifier files were created as well.
From what I've read, these files are normally invisible on Windows, but I can see them just fine. My problem is that I can't seem to delete them.

An example of such a file is `ATKPackage_Win7_64_Z100020.zip:Zone.Identifier`. Upon attempting to delete the file, I will just be told that the file cannot be found.

Things I've tried so far:

- Deleting from the command line
- Rebooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `chkdsk /f c:` from the command line fixed the issue for me. You may change the drive letter as needed, or run the same disk check through the drive's properties dialog:

Click "Check now..." in the Properties dialog for the drive in question:
[image: Check disk]

Make sure "Automatically fix file system errors" is enabled:
[image: Automatically fix errors]